# How to select records from January 1, 2021 to last week

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I was wondering how to make a query where I can select data from Jan 1, 21 to last week. I tried to put it in the date filter like this:

```
where start_date between TO_DATE('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
                     and TO_DATE('2021-06-13', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

but I would have to manually go in every week to change the end date, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to select for data up until last week (meaning data until Sunday) from today's week, so that even if I run the query two days from today, I only get data from Jan 1 to this past Sunday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `TRUNC`ate `SYSDATE` to the start of the ISO-week (which will always be a Monday) and then find the values which are less than that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  start_date >= DATE '2021-01-01'
AND    start_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
```

This has the advantage that it is independent of language and location so the query will behave exactly the same regardless of any settings the database or the user's session may have.

It will also get **all** the values that may occur on Sunday (from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`).

If you want the value from the start of the current year (rather than from the fixed lower bound of `2021-01-01`) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  start_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' )
AND    start_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e14bb9c4e80a59a7b135394afffcbd0)*

Comment: thank you but how do I structure it in my query? What does 'IW' mean?

Comment: @comp_user I've given you a complete query in the answer and a db<>fiddle with a demonstration of it working; I am not sure what more you want when you ask "how do I structure it in my query". And, as I said in the first line, truncating to the start of the ISO-week (which is specified by ISO8601 and is always midnight Monday) by using the `IW` format model. You can search the internet for [Oracle format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) and find out more information if you want.

Comment: does anyone know how to keep the query flexible, I understand the above example provides data from Jan 1, 21 to the last Sunday as I asked in my original question above, but sometimes we have user requests where data is requested until last Friday or last Thursday instead of last Sunday, I would appreciate if someone could give me an understandable answer of how that can be achieved. Thank you

Comment: @comp_user That is beyond the scope of the current question; you should ask it as a new question rather than trying to broaden the scope of the existing question. But you can just find the start of the ISO week and then subtract 2 days to find the upper bound for last Friday `AND start_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - 2`.

Comment: thank you, I will look up more on 'sysdate and iw', it seems that they are useful sql functions to use rather than manually changing the date parameters every time we receive a new request for a certain date range

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood it, you're looking for a **row generator**. If that's so, here you are:

First, a few settings (as my database *speaks* Croatian); you wouldn't do that:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy, day';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.
```

Query itself, and the result:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + level - 1 as datum
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= next_day(trunc(sysdate) - 7, 'sunday') - trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + 1
  4  order by datum;

DATUM
---------------------
01.01.2021, friday
02.01.2021, saturday
03.01.2021, sunday
04.01.2021, monday
05.01.2021, tuesday
06.01.2021, wednesday
07.01.2021, thursday
08.01.2021, friday
<snip>
09.06.2021, wednesday
10.06.2021, thursday
11.06.2021, friday
12.06.2021, saturday
13.06.2021, sunday

164 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

As you said:

> so that even if I run the query two days from today, I only get data from Jan 1 to this past Sunday?

let's *pretend* it is two days from today, i.e. 16.06.2021 (Wednesday). I'm now connected as a privileged user so that I could change system's date (you wouldn't be doing that):

```
SQL> alter system set fixed_date = '16.06.2021';

System altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy, day';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------------------
16.06.2021, wednesday
```

See? Wednesday.

Let's try the same query again:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + level - 1 as datum
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= next_day(trunc(sysdate) - 7, 'sunday') - trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + 1
  4  order by datum;

DATUM
---------------------
01.01.2021, friday
02.01.2021, saturday
03.01.2021, sunday
04.01.2021, monday
<snip>
11.06.2021, friday
12.06.2021, saturday
13.06.2021, sunday

164 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Looks OK to me.

Comment: thank you but when I run this query, I only get data until 5 pm of Sunday, I am not getting the data uptil Sunday 11:59pm

Answer (score -1):

You can use below where clause -

```
WHERE start_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'd'));
```

Comment: This gives different results depending on the territory used by the database (or set in the user's session) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2bb28a33c61c7739087e63580376bc3a)

Comment: Result of `TO_CHAR(..., 'd')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` settings, it may not be reliable.